# Modify list of directories name from Command Prompt

Tags: windows, directory, cmd

I have one requirement to modify name for list of directories through command prompt. Operating system is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Example - I do have following directory structure

- ROOT

  - 123#5

    - 11
    - 22
  - 123#6

    - 11
    - 22
    - 33
  - 123#7
  - 123#8

    - 44

I want to update above mentioned directory structure as following structure through batch file or command prompt.

- ROOT

  - 123~5

    - 11
    - 22
  - 123~6

    - 11
    - 22
    - 33
  - 123~7
  - 123~8

    - 44

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r "C:\root" %%d in (.) do (
  set dirname=%%~nxd
  echo !dirname! | findstr "#" >nul
  if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
    set newname=!dirname:#=~!
    ren "%%~dpnd" "!newname!"
  )
)

endlocal
```